# what is the difference between AsyncTaskTarget and AsyncWrapper Target in NLog 4.5?

Tags: asp.net, logging, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, nlog

What is the difference between [AsyncTaskTarget](http://nlog-project.org/documentation/v4.5.0/html/T_NLog_Targets_AsyncTaskTarget.htm) and [AsyncWrapper](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/AsyncWrapper-target)?

Which is better?

I have seen that AsyncWrapper has more config options (like **queueLimit**, **overflowAction** & more) which is important for me (I don't want logs to get discarded, even if more than 10000 logs buffered, since I am working on a website for some big company).

So, is that the only difference?

Why then we even have something like AsyncTaskTarget?

Moreover, what happens if I combined both AsyncTaskTarget & AsyncWrapper with something like this:

```
CustomTargetExtendingAsyncTaskTarget customTarget = CustomTargetExtendingAsyncTaskTarget();
AsyncTargetWrapper asyncTargetWrapper = new AsyncTargetWrapper(customTarget, 100000, AsyncTargetWrapperOverflowAction.Grow);
```

is this a bad idea?

Comment: See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/2872

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In summary:

- The AsyncTarget is a target to wrap around other targets to give them Async behavior. Good to know, the `async=true` that could be applied in the nlog.config is internally also the AsyncWrapper.

  For example, writing async to a file:

  ```
  <target name="target2" xsi:type="AsyncWrapper">
     <target name ="target1" xsi:type="File"
              fileName="c:/temp/test.log" layout="${message}"
              keepFileOpen="true" />
  </target>
  ```
- The AsyncTaskTarget is an (abstract) base class for creating custom targets (e.g. in C#) with async behavior. You cannot use the AsyncTaskTarget in your nlog.config

  Rolf describes it nicely: 
   (from https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/2872)

  > AsyncTaskTarget is a base-class just like TargetWithLayout for creating your own custom Target. It makes it easier to make one chain of tasks with timeout-handling. By default it will ensure the Logger is not stalled, as it just writes to the internal-queue (and schedules a writer-task if none is active).